# Injecting data into Docusign Template to create document and capture signature

Tags: docusignapi

I created a template and to use that I upload a excel with list of user's name and email. Then docusign send the email to recipients and signature is captured.

I want to automate part of it. Have a link in application that should fetch the document to sign [ parameter for templates - logged in user's name and email ] and then display the document for user to sign. How this can be achieved in java web application... we are using Oracle ADF for application.

Comment: Please EDIT your question to add more information: do you want your application to provide an embedded signing experience? Do you want to use a template but have a different document for each embedded signer? Please be specific.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please upvote all useful questions, including those to others' questions. And PLEASE check/accept the best answer to each of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

This [Code Example Launcher](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant) should help.

If you are looking to have your end-users **sign via email**, you can

(1) Utilize Bulk Send functionality to send a DocuSign template to a list of different users. [See this guide](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/bulk-sending-envelopes)

If, however, you are hoping to **embed Docusign in your app**, I would suggest you investigate

(2) Building embedded signing with a template. Specifically, Check out [example #13](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant).

Comment: Hi Matthew, welcome to StackOverflow! Answers that are only links [are not good answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please add the relevant code from the link into your answer.